# MS Access error 3151 ODBC error --> ORACLE 11G

Tags: ms-access, odbc, oracle11g, dao

I have an MS Access 2003 DB that was created by a contractor who has now left. The DB uses linked tables and DAO to connect to an ORACLE backend. It used to work until we recently upgraded our ORACLE version from 10g to 11g. As part of the upgrade we had to update our rather out dated "Microsoft ODBC for ORACLE" driver to "Oracle in instantclient11_1" thats forms part of the ORACLE Instant Client.

When we run the VBA it returns error code 3151 and says "ODBC --connection to 'MYDB' failed. I did a bit of googling and found that code 3151 is a generic code. However sometimes this works and other times(80% of the time) it doesn't.

Its installed on an MS Xp SP3 32bit machine and the drivers are 32-bit. From The ODBC Manager when I run the test connection it is always successful and I can query the DB from within excel and using the "Import External data"

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: In my relatively limited dealings with Oracle, I have read that the Instant Clients can present their own peculiar set of problems. You might consider removing/uninstalling the Instant Client and go with the conventional client setup and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Are you sure the DSN name is the same as before? If not, you will need to rename to DSN to what Access is looking for, or update the linked table definitions in Access.

Comment: How do you connect in both cases to oracle?

Comment: @nicholas I'm using the same DSN name. I have removed the old one to ensure theres, no conflict

Comment: @DavidW could you explain what you mean by "conventional client setup"?

Comment: Surely. Oracle's client networking components include the conventional/normal client, and a "lighter weight" version called Instant Client. When you install the Oracle client, you normally have to explicitly choose the Instant Client. I had to make sure *not* to install it in conjunction with some tools I wrote, as I had read during development that the Instant Client did not always "work and play well with others..."

Comment: I just thought about it today, and it may not be enough to just ensure that the DSN names are the same. Depending on how you are connecting to these tables (linked tables, passthru queries, etc.) the connection strings may have more information, such as the Driver version, stored in them. Perhaps delete and recreate your links to see how that goes.